# Algorithm to convert string from one format to other

Tags: algorithm

I was looking at a problem which stated to convert strings as below.

```
s = "3[a]2[bc]", return "aaabcbc".
s = "3[a2[c]]", return "accaccacc".
s = "2[abc]3[cd]ef", return "abcabccdcdcdef".
```

I was able to understand how to do that.

I was thinking is there a way to do this in **reverse**. when given a string like `abcabccdcdcdef` I understand there can be many possibilities of representation. I was looking can we do it in representation which takes lowest memory(Not algorithmic but of the final string).

Comment: No not a homework. I was doing [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/decode-string/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the minimum length RLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261318/finding-the-minimum-length-rle)

Comment: Check out the older question. Your case appears to be more complicated (with nesting and brackets), but AFAICT this approach should work for you too.

Comment: I am thinking if that answer works for nesting?

Comment: @user168983 It can be adapted probably, but at the expense of becoming cubic or quartic.

Answer (score 1):

for max efficiency, we'd want to have as much reduction as possible. I think I would do something like this (it may not be the most efficient algorithm):

```
s = "whateverwhateveryouwantwantwantababababababababc"
possibilities = []
repeats = []
def findRepeats(repeats, s, length):
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 2 * length + 1):
        if s[i:i+length] == s[i+length:i+2*length]:
            trackInd = i+length
            times = 2
            while trackInd+2*length <= len(s):
                if (s[trackInd:trackInd+length]==s[trackInd+length:trackInd+2*length]):
                    times += 1
                else: break
                trackInd += length

            repeats.append((i, times, s[i:i+length]))

    return repeats

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    repeats = findRepeats(repeats, s, i)

def formPossibility(repeats, s):
    build = ""
    i = 0
    while i < len(s):
        pass = True
        for repeat in repeats:
            if repeat[0] == i:
                pass = False
                build += repeat[1] + "["
                build += repeat[2] + "]"
                break

        if pass:
            build += s[i]

# I didn't finish this but you would loop through all the repeats and test
# them to see if they overlap, and then you would take all the posibilities
# of different ways to make them so that some are there, and some are not.
# in any case, I think that you get the idea.
# I couldn't finish this because I am doing the coding on stackoverflow and
# its like so painful and so hard to debug. also I don't have enough time sorry
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it is the most efficient or if it is efficient at all, but here is my approach using js.

```js
function format(pattern, length, times) {
    var result = "";
    if (times == 0) {
        result = pattern;
    } else {
        result = (times + 1).toString() + "[" + pattern + "]";
    }
    return result;
}

function encode(input) {
    var result = "";
    var pattern = { length: 1, times: 0 };
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= input.length / 2) {
        var subpattern = input.substr(0, i);
        var j = 0;
        while (input.substr(i + j * i, i) == subpattern && j + i < input.length) {
            j++;
        }
        if (i * j > pattern.length * pattern.times) {
            pattern.length = i;
            pattern.times = j;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if (pattern.length > 1) {
        result = format(encode(input.substr(0, pattern.length)), pattern.length, pattern.times);
    } else {
        result = format(input.substr(0, pattern.length), pattern.length, pattern.times);
    }
    if (pattern.length + pattern.length * pattern.times < input.length) {
        result += encode(input.substr(pattern.length + pattern.length * pattern.times, input.length));
    }
    return result;
}
```